# session.removeAttribute doesn't work in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am removing a session through `session.removeAttribute(attribute_name);`.
But through this session attribute is not removed actually. How can I remove a particular session attribute? Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: `I am removing session through session.removeAttribute(attribute_name);` You cannot remove session by this method, you can remove an attribute from session, which I think you are trying to do. But what problem are you facing? Show some code here.

Comment: removeAttribute will definitely remove the attributes from the session. Make sure about the sttribute name. Alternative way of removing attribute is `session.setAttribute(attribute_name, null);`

Comment: Is this happening with a specific attribute or every attribute you try? maybe you are working with a wrapper around the session object which prevents attribute deletion

Comment: make sure your attribute name is right :)

Comment: thanks everyone.In my web application ..at the time of logout I invalidate the session through session.invalidate()..Now the problem is that when I open web pages of my application in multiple tabs,then when I click logout in one tab..it perfectly logs out but after that when I switch to other tab which was already opened and I refresh that page then again session is created without login.Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

In order to remove/delete session completely, use `session.invalidate()` method. If you just want to remove a particular attribute then use `session.removeAttribute(attribute_name)` but make sure attribute_name is right and not null.

Comment: thanks...
this worked but now I am facing one more problem.
In my web application ..at the time of logout I invalidate the session through session.invalidate()..Now the problem is that when I open web pages of my application in multiple tabs,then when I click logout in one tab..it perfectly logs out but after that when I switch to other tab which was already opened and I refresh that page then again session is created without login.Please help me.

Comment: Yes it's expected behavior. When you refresh your page a new session will be created not the one you have invalidated. Note that this newly created session does not have any user-bound attribute therefore It won't have your login information. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually I have solved that problem.Now what I want to achieve is...I want to check at my jsp page that from what type of device the HTTP request is coming..means whether its from android phone or IOS phone or the system web-browser ??

Comment: sadly, it still does not work for me. I remove within handlerA with: session.removeAttribute("abc"). After this i send ajax-get-request on handlerB and my "abc"-Attribute is still within a session :(

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code in your **`jsp file`**

i am sure this will do
if not ping me

```
 response.setHeader("cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"); 
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");    
 response.setHeader("Expires","0");
```